# Assign to variable or return it right away doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift

If I do this:

```
func myFunc() -> NSRange{
    var range = s.rangeOfString(searchText, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch)
    return s.rangeOfString(searchText, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch)
}
```

I get an error that says there's extra arguments in the second call. But they are exactly the same!

On the other hand, this works fine:

```
func myFunc() -> NSRange{
    var range = s.rangeOfString(searchText, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch)
    return range
}
```

My question is implicit. So here it is: why swift compiler doesn't get satisfied with the first option and instead it makes me assign the return of the function to a variable first?

If that works for you, here's my full code:

```
var a: [MyObject] = []
array = a.filter{
                var b = ($0 as MyObject).molecule.name
                var s: NSString = b as NSString
                var range = s.rangeOfString(searchText, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch)
                return s.rangeOfString(searchText, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch)
                return range.location != -1
            }
```

Comment: The one that downvoted please consider adding a comment so I know what's going on.

Comment: Please post your code example as text. Your lines of code are 5 pixels tall... And if someone wanted to copy the code into a playground to test solutions out, they cannot do that from an image.

Comment: Your first example works fine for me in a playground: https://gist.github.com/Squeegy/fc2516cd3c3a9e6f8f5a What else can you tell us?

Comment: @AlexWayne added another example to my question. I'm using this inside a filter{}

Comment: MyObject and Reagent was the same class, sorry.

Comment: .. why do you have two returns?

Comment: @DSM I was testing the code. So I just copied-pasted the part where the error was. But having two returns doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is different than what Swift reports. The error reporting in Swift can be pretty strange at times.

The real problem is that `filter` expects a boolean value to be returned, representing if that item should be included. But `rangeOfString` returns an `NSRange`.

So if you return an expression that yields a boolean value, it works fine.

```
return s.rangeOfString(
  searchText,
  options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch
).location != NSNotFound
```

---

Which is why your first example works fine. You say this function returns an `NSRange` and then you return an `NSRange` so it works!

```
func myFunc() -> NSRange{
    var range = s.rangeOfString(searchText, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch)
    return s.rangeOfString(searchText, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch)
}
```

Comment: You're right. And just like C++ error reporting can be really misleading. That does not help developer.

Comment: I've gotten in the habit of just looking around for anything strange when I get a Swift error message I don't understand. And in this case returning an `NSRange` to `filter` is strange.